# Como analizar un certificado SSL?

Tags: python, web, ssl, certificado

me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma de poder obtener el certificado de una página web y obtener datos como la fecha de vencimiento, a que dominio pertenece y la entidad certificadora. Hay una librera de python "pyOpenSSL"pero no termino de comprender bien su funcionamiento. Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: El propio navegador te muestra esos detalles, con darle al icono que hay a la izquierda de la URL

Comment: Lo sé, pero lo que quiero saber una forma para obtener esos datos y utilizarlos en un programa, no sé... que me imprima en pantalla si la fecha ya expiró o algo por el estilo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar la biblioteca `ssl` que viene de serie con Python.

Es un poco complejo porque para poder acceder a los contenidos "procesados" del certificado necesitas previamente verificarlo (al menos con esta biblioteca) y verificar los certificados implica que has de tener un archivo de certificados-raiz (entidades autenticadoras).

En una máquina Unix tienes uno de estos ficheros en `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-*.crt`. En una máquina Windows no sé dónde estará tal fichero, pero tiene que haber uno (los navegadores a veces traen también uno).

Suponiendo que has conseguido un fichero de certificados raiz con el nombre `ca-certificates.crt`, el siguiente código muestra cómo crear un socket SSL, usarlo para conectar por HTTPS a un sitio (`python.org`) y obtener su certificado ya procesado en forma de diccionario python:

```
import ssl
import pprint

context = ssl.create_default_context()
context = ssl.SSLContext()
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_verify_locations("ca-certificates.crt")
conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),
                            server_hostname="www.python.org")
conn.connect(("www.python.org", 443))

cert = conn.getpeercert()

pprint.pprint(cert)
```

Resultado:

```
{'OCSP': ('http://ocsp.digicert.com',),
 'caIssuers': ('http://cacerts.digicert.com/DigiCertSHA2ExtendedValidationServerCA.crt',),
 'crlDistributionPoints': ('http://crl3.digicert.com/sha2-ev-server-g2.crl',
                           'http://crl4.digicert.com/sha2-ev-server-g2.crl'),
 'issuer': ((('countryName', 'US'),),
            (('organizationName', 'DigiCert Inc'),),
            (('organizationalUnitName', 'www.digicert.com'),),
            (('commonName', 'DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA'),)),
 'notAfter': 'Oct 14 12:00:00 2020 GMT',
 'notBefore': 'Sep 18 00:00:00 2018 GMT',
 'serialNumber': '0E5ECF181783006D9BAC453611F54912',
 'subject': ((('businessCategory', 'Private Organization'),),
             (('jurisdictionCountryName', 'US'),),
             (('jurisdictionStateOrProvinceName', 'Delaware'),),
             (('serialNumber', '3359300'),),
             (('countryName', 'US'),),
             (('stateOrProvinceName', 'New Hampshire'),),
             (('localityName', 'Wolfeboro'),),
             (('organizationName', 'Python Software Foundation'),),
             (('commonName', 'www.python.org'),)),
 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'bugs.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'wiki.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'hg.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'mail.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'pypi.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'packaging.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'login.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'discuss.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'us.pycon.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'pypi.io'),
                    ('DNS', 'docs.pypi.io'),
                    ('DNS', 'pypi.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'docs.pypi.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'donate.pypi.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'devguide.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'www.bugs.python.org'),
                    ('DNS', 'python.org')),
 'version': 3}
```

En el campo `notAfter` tienes la fecha de caducidad, por ejemplo.

Comment: Perfecto, muchisimas gracias por la ayuda.